# Fourier transform all steps walkthrough for wave vector $k$ and $x$

Tags: analysis, special-functions

Below is my walkthrough of a fourier transform. My problem is that I want to do all the similar steps for a fourier transform between position x and the wave vector k. That is working on a solution of the maxwell equations. The maxwell equations has many possible solutions for example:

$ cos(kx-\omega t)+isin(kx - \omega t)$

But I don't know how to start up with it in a sum of cos and sin and end up with a transform. One of the problems that I see is that I don't have any denumerator like L that can go to infinity and can be interchanged for something that goes to 0 in $\delta k$ I have added all the steps below because I need a directly point to where I must change something in order to get the fourier transform for the wave vector and position. Look for the bold part below for my main problem, Just scroll down there to get directly to the question. The rest of the text is just to avoid overlooking any linear additions and arrangments that might be the problem.

$$
\int_{-L}^{L}\sin\frac{2m\pi}{L}t\, dt=0  \tag A
$$

$$
\int_{-L}^{L}\cos\frac{2m\pi}{L}t\, dt=0
$$

$$
\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos\frac{2n
\pi}{L}t\sin\frac{2m\pi}{L}t\right] \,dt
$$

Using standard trigonometric relations:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L}(\frac{2m
\pi}{L}-\frac{2n
\pi}{L})t + sin(\frac{2m
\pi}{L}+\frac{2n
\pi}{L})t dt\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L}sin(\frac{2
\pi}{L}(m-n))t + sin(\frac{2
\pi}{L}(m+n))t dt\\
\end{align}

For m=n

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L} 0 + sin(\frac{2
\pi}{L}(2m))t dt=0\\
\end{align}

$ m\neq n $  We have the same integral as in (A) which is zero for integers m,n

\begin{align}
\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{1}{2}[sin\frac{2n
\pi}{L}tsin\frac{2m\pi}{L}t] dt\\
\end{align}

Using standard trigonometric relations:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L}cos(\frac{2m
\pi}{L}-\frac{2n
\pi}{L})t - (\frac{2m
\pi}{L}+\frac{2n
\pi}{L})t dt   \ \ \ (B) \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L}cos(\frac{2
\pi}{L}(m-n))t - (\frac{2m
\pi}{L}(m+n))t dt\\
\end{align}

for $ m \neq n $ we get sine when it is inegrated and it is 0 for all + and - of integers m,n

when m=n   m+n becomes 0 as well for the same reason as when $ m \neq n $

but for m-n

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L}cos(\frac{2
\pi}{L})t  dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L}1 dt=L\\
\end{align}

since cos0=1

\begin{align}
\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{1}{2}[cos\frac{2n
\pi}{L}tcos\frac{2m\pi}{L}t] dt\\
\end{align}

Using standard trigonometric relations:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L}cos(\frac{2m
\pi}{L}+\frac{2n
\pi}{L})t + cos(\frac{2m
\pi}{L}-\frac{2n
\pi}{L})t dt\\
\end{align}

for similar reasoning as in (B) $ m \neq n $  everything is 0

for m=n

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L}cos(\frac{2m
\pi}{L}-\frac{2n
\pi}{L})t dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L} 1 dt\\
\end{align}

The fourier series are given by:

$f(x)=\sum_{=0}^{\infty}a_n'$ + $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n'sin(nx)$

$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}a_0 +   $   $\sum_{=1}^{\infty}a_n$ + $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_nsin(nx) \ \ \ (C)$

Multipying with $ cos\frac{k\pi x}{L} $

$f(x)cos\frac{k\pi x}{L}=cos\frac{k\pi x}{L} \frac{1}{2}a_0 +   $   $\sum_{=1}^{\infty}cos\frac{k\pi x}{L}a_ncos\frac{n\pi x}{L}$ + $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}cos\frac{k\pi x}{L}b_nsin\frac{n\pi x}{L} \ \ \ (C)$

Putting integration signs on both sides and using trigonometric relations above we obtain

$\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)cos\frac{k\pi x}{L} dx=\int_{-L}^{L}cos\frac{k\pi x}{L} \frac{1}{2}a_0 dx +   $   $\int_{-L}^{L}\sum_{=1}^{\infty}cos\frac{k\pi x}{L}a_ncos\frac{n\pi x}{L} dx$ + $\int_{-L}^{L}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}cos\frac{k\pi x}{L}b_nsin\frac{n\pi x}{L} dx\ \ \ $

$\int_{-L}^{L}cos\frac{k\pi x}{L} \frac{1}{2}a_0 dx =0$

$\int_{-L}^{L}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}cos\frac{k\pi x}{L}b_nsin\frac{n\pi x}{L} dx=0$

$a_k=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x)cos\frac{k\pi x}{L} dx  (D) $

if we instad multiply with $ sin\frac{k\pi x}{L} $ and doing the same we obtain

$b_k=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x)sin\frac{k\pi x}{L} dx  (E) $

Normal complex number relation:

$ e^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}}=cos\frac{n\pi x}{L} + isin\frac{n\pi x}{L} $

from symmetry:

$ e^{-in\frac{\pi x}{L}}=cos\frac{n\pi x}{L} - isin\frac{n\pi x}{L} $

addition and subtraction from theese two equations gives:

$ e^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}}+e^{-in\frac{\pi x}{L}}=2cos x $

$ e^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}}-e^{-in\frac{\pi x}{L}}=2isin x $

$ a_ncos\frac{n\pi x}{L} + b_nsin\frac{n\pi x}{L}=\frac{a_n}{2}(e^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}}+e^{-in\frac{\pi x}{L}})+\frac{b_n}{i2}(e^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}}-e^{-in\frac{\pi x}{L}}) $

using $ \frac{1}{i}=-i $

$ a_ncos\frac{n\pi x}{L} + b_nsin\frac{n\pi x}{L}=(\frac{a_n}{2}-\frac{b_n}{i2})e^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}}+(\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{b_n}{i2})e^{-in\frac{\pi x}{L}}) $

$ c_n=\frac{a_n}{2}-\frac{b_ni}{2} \\\ c_n*=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{b_ni}{2} $

We can now rewrite the fourier series:

$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}a_0 +   $   $\sum_{=1}^{\infty}a_ncos\frac{n\pi x}{L}$ + $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_nsin\frac{n\pi x}{L} \ \ \ =\frac{1}{2}a_0 +   $   $\sum_{=1}^{\infty}c_ne^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}}+c_n*e^{-in\frac{\pi x}{L}}) $

if we let the last part go from $ -\infty$ to -1 we can redifine the name of the constants keeping in mind that $e^0=1$ for $c_0=\frac{1}{2}a_0$ and get:

$f(x)=   \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}} \ \ \ (F) $

using (D):

$c_0=\frac{a_k}{2}=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x) dx  (G) $

$c_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-ib_n)=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}  f(x)cos\frac{k\pi x}{L} - if(x)sin\frac{k\pi x}{L}  dx $

$c_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-ib_n)=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x)e^{-\frac{k\pi x}{L}}  dx \ \ \ (H) $

$c_n*=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+ib_n)=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x) e^{\frac{k\pi x}{L}}  dx $

by letting n=-1,-2,-3..

$c_n*=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+ib_n)=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x) e^{-\frac{k\pi x}{L}}  dx \ \ \ (I) $

similar as for the discrete case we get by adding (G), (H) and (I):

$c_n=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x) e^{-\frac{k\pi x}{L}}  dx \ \ \ for -\infty<n<\infty $

using (F) we get

$f(x)=   \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L} e^{-\frac{k\pi x}{L}}e^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}} \ \ \  $

**Here is where L goes to infinity dont know what to do for the wave vector**

Letting $ L\rightarrow \infty $

$f(x)=   \lim_{L\to \infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x') e^{-\frac{k\pi x}{L}}e^{in\frac{\pi x}{L}} \ \ \  $

$ \frac{\delta k}{2\pi}=\frac{1}{L} $

$f(x)=   \lim_{\delta k\to 0}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\delta k}{2 \pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{\delta k}}^{\frac{\pi}{\delta k}}f(x') e^{-in \delta k x}e^{in\delta k x} \ \ \  $

$g(k)=f(x') e^{-ikx'}  dx'\ \ \  $

$ k=n\delta k$

lets us add the sigma sum like an integral

$f(x)=  \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(k)e^{ik x} \ \ \  $

Comment: You might want to give a quick initial summary of what you want as that is a lot to wade through...

Comment: It looks like most of this post is not directly relevant to the question. You should edit it to be clearer about what you want to know, and remove most of the "walkthrough".